# Random Sentence Generator in Ruby : How to randomly select values on specific key in hash?

Tags: ruby, random, hash

I'm working on a Ruby verison of RSG and somehow stuck on the sentence generating process (...)

so I managed to implement all functions like read, convert to hash...,etc. But problem is how to randomly pick values in hash to generate the sentence?

Now I have a hash here:

```
hash = {"<start>"=>[["The", "<object>", "<verb>", "tonight."]],
        "<object>"=>[["waves"], ["big", "yellow", "flowers"], ["slugs"]], 
        "<verb>"=>[["sigh", "<adverb>"], ["portend", "like", "<object>"],["die", "<adverb>"]], 
        "<adverb>"=>[["warily"], ["grumpily"]]}
```

The Objective is to assemble the strings using random values in the hash for example when the function iterates to `"<object>"`, it will take it as a key and search in the hash to find matching key then randomly pick the corresponding values (one of the strings in `"<object>"=>[["waves"], ["big", "yellow", "flowers"], ["slugs"]]`) and assemble it, then the output would be something like this:

```
"The waves sigh warily tonight"
```

My code so far:

```
hash.each do |_, value|
  value.map{|x| x.map{|y| is_non_terminal?(y) ? (puts value.values_at("SomethingToPutInto")) : (puts y)}}
end
```

Somehow the logics in the code becomes too complicated and I'm stuck on this step.. Using `values_at` will cause TypeError: `no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)`

For `is_non_terminal?(y)` is just a function to check whether the string contains `<` and `>`:

```
def is_non_terminal?(s)
   s.include?('<' && '>') ? true : false
end
```

Comment: Is there a reason to start with a data structure of that format? Or are you open to alternatives?

Comment: @MarkThomas yeah that data structure is required due to my HW requirement.

Comment: Why is the value for `"<object>"` `[["waves"], ["big", "yellow", "flowers"], ["slugs"]]`? Why wouldn't it be `[["waves"], ["big"], ["yellow"], ["flowers"], ["slugs"]]`? In your example sentence, "yellow" appears on its own without "big" or "flowers."

Comment: @moveson if that's the case the output would be "big yellow flowers".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume they're looking for a recursive method, let's call it `generate`.

```
def generate(key)
```

Read the hash at the key and take one randomly using `sample`:

```
  words = @hash[key].sample
```

Then, for each word, check to see if it's a `<key>`. If so, call `generate` on it, otherwise save it:

```
    if (word.start_with?("<") && word.end_with?(">"))
      generate(word)
    else
      @sentence << word
    end
```

Putting it all together:

```
@hash = {"<start>"=>[["The", "<object>", "<verb>", "tonight."]],
        "<object>"=>[["waves"], ["big", "yellow", "flowers"], ["slugs"]], 
        "<verb>"=>[["sigh", "<adverb>"], ["portend", "like", "<object>"],["die", "<adverb>"]], 
        "<adverb>"=>[["warily"], ["grumpily"]]}

@sentence = []

def generate(key)
  words = @hash[key].sample
  words.each do |word|
    if (word.start_with?("<") && word.end_with?(">"))
      generate(word)
    else
      @sentence << word
    end
  end
end

generate("<start>")
puts @sentence.join(" ")
```

Notice I used @-variables to make their scope reachable from within the method.

Sample output: `The big yellow flowers sigh grumpily tonight.`

Comment: Not sure if you've been taught recursion yet, but as you can see, it makes for very brief code.

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
def generate(hash, start_key)
  mod_hash = hash.transform_values{ |v| v.map { |a| a.join(' ') } }
  sentence = mod_hash[start_key].sample
  while sentence.include?('<')
    sentence.gsub!(/\<.+?\>/) { |s| mod_hash[s].sample }
  end
  sentence
end
```

**Examples**

```
hash = { "<start>" =>[["The", "<object>", "<verb>", "tonight."]],
         "<object>"=>[["waves"], ["big", "yellow", "flowers"], ["slugs"]],
         "<verb>"  =>[["sigh", "<adverb>"], ["portend", "like", "<object>"],
                      ["die", "<adverb>"]],
         "<adverb>"=>[["warily"], ["grumpily"]]}

generate(hash, '<start>') #=> "The big yellow flowers die grumpily tonight."
generate(hash, '<start>') #=> "The waves die warily tonight."
generate(hash, '<start>') #=> "The slugs sigh warily tonight."
generate(hash, '<verb>')  #=> "portend like big yellow flowers"
```

**Explanation**

Firstly, `mod_hash` is constructed.

```
mod_hash = hash.transform_values{ |v| v.map { |a| a.join(' ') } }
  #=> {"<start>" =>["The <object> <verb> tonight."],
  #    "<object>"=>["waves", "big yellow flowers", "slugs"],
  #    "<verb>"  =>["sigh <adverb>", "portend like <object>", "die <adverb>"],
  #    "<adverb>"=>["warily", "grumpily"]}
```

Then the initial sentence is obtained.

```
start_key = '<start>'
sentence = mod_hash[start_key].sample
  #=> "The <object> <verb> tonight."
```

We now simply replace each word in `sentence` that begins `'<'` and ends `'>'` with a randomly-selected element of the value of that key in `mod_hash` (the value being an array of strings). This continues until there are no more such words in `sentence`.

The question mark in the regex means that one or more characters are to be matched *lazily*. That means that the match is terminated as soon as the first `'>'` is encountered. If, for example, the sentence were `"a <hat> and <cat>!"`, the regex would match both `<hat>` and `<cat>`. By contrast, if the match were *greedy* (the default), it would match `"<hat> and <cat>"`, which of course is not a key of `mod_hash`.

Note that `hash` could have a structure that results in a non-terminating sequence of replacements.

See [Hash#transform_values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values).